# How to insert current year and next year using sql query in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
    Dim sCon As New SQLConnect


    strSql = " select distinct DATEPART(yyyy,fl_date) as fl_date " & _
                " from attendancemast" & _
                " where 1 = 1" & _
                " order by fl_date"
    '" union " & _ commented
    '" select year(GETDATE())" commented





    sCon.sqlCmd.CommandText = strSql
    sCon.sqlReader = sCon.sqlCmd.ExecuteReader

    cboYear.Items.Clear()
    cboYear.Items.Add(New ListItem("", ""))
    While sCon.sqlReader.Read
        cboYear.Items.Add(New ListItem(sCon.sqlReader("fl_date")))
    End While
    sCon.sqlReader.Close()
```

in this sql query i am selecting year 2004 to 2013 from my database and i want to fill dropdown by current year and next year in this query by union mehtod

Comment: why not use a BETWEEN clause?

Comment: how to use please tell me

Comment: @user3614933 You can look at the SQL Server documentation to start. I'll leave finding the documentation as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I question the need to open a SQL connection to get the current year and next year, but this will do that.

```
SELECT YEAR(GetDate()) as fl_date
UNION SELECT YEAR(GetDate()) + 1
```